# A program similar to iperf that uses "uncompressable" blocks of data to properly test the connection with compression

Tags: networking, performance

Can anyone point to a program similar to `iperf`, which avoids biasing of the connection bandwidth measurement due to connection compression enabled?

It seems that `iperf` measures the connection spedd by sending some zero data across the connection. When measuring the connection with enabled compression (like `openvp` tunnel) such data that is sent is compressed effectively, and data transfer measurement is not accurate.

Please advise the program (or way to use `iperf`) so that the compression is negligible (like in case of sending the `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` prepared chunks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I've found the solution: `iperf` itself has an option to use prepared data for transfer. The option is `-F`. In case we want to pipe the data from another application to `iperf`, one may use `-I` option (read data from `stdin`).

The test routine I used is as follows (using 1GB file):

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/urandom.dat bs=1M count=1000
iperf -c iperf-server -F /tmp/urandom.dat
```

Comment: ... nice! I just tried `iperf -c iperf-server -F /dev/urandom` which seems to work as well

Comment: ... but using the device directly seems a bad idea: its very slow on my system, slower than the link speed.

Comment: @moritz you're basically measuring the speed of `urandom` device instead of the link speed